# Can I increase the volume of an audio file - android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I'm having two audio files which I play automatically when an activity starts without any interaction from user but I'm having a low volume audio file and higher volume audio file. My question is: how to use setVolume(float, float) to balance between both files.

Comment: Maybe just a simple fixed audio solution: can you edit your audio files with any audio editing software?

Comment: If you're using `MediaPlayer` then you can use `setVolume()`.

Comment: @DavidLee yes I know there is setVolume in MediaPlayer but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @DavidLee If you could explain the right volume and left volume I would be very thankful especially that I've read android documentation

Comment: You can do it like the following: `mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f)` and of course, you can change the values to whatever you want. If you want to set the actual volume (to be heard by users) to be the same, I believe you would have to adjust the values (manually; trial-and-error method).